# how do i fix when UIColor colorwithRed green blue only show blue color regardless of the RGB float value?

Tags: ios, colors, uicolor

Im trying to save color values in array where the color ranges from light red color to total red color .

```
float INCREMENT = 0.05;
for (float greenblue = 0.80; greenblue > 0; greenblue -= INCREMENT) {
    UIColor *Redcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00
                                        green:greenblue
                                         blue:greenblue
                                        alpha:1.0];
    [self.RedColors addObject:Redcolor];
}
```

This is how I save the UIColors in the array.

The problem comes in when I try to use these color values for setTintColor.

Comment: Does `self.RedColors` have the values you expect in it?

Comment: when I try tinting the color separately, it works. However, when I'm trying to set the array of color values thru that loop, all the color values are blue

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UIColor *colorVal = (UIColor*) [self.RedColors objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];

[view setTintColor:colorVal];
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

For UIColor in objective C, don't forget to divide it by 255.0 as below:-

```
float INCREMENT = 0.05/255.0f;
for (float greenblue = 0.80/255.0f; greenblue > 0/255.0f; greenblue -= INCREMENT) {
    UIColor *Redcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00/255.0f
                                        green:greenblue
                                         blue:greenblue
                                        alpha:1.0];
    [self.RedColors addObject:Redcolor];
}
```